# Catch Event in react-leaflet map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I wounder how I can catch **`zoomstart`** and **`zoomend`** events on react-leaflet map component.

I have some custom non-geographics map

```
            <Map
                center={this.getCalculatedCenterFromState()}
                zoom={this.getCalculatedZoomFromState()}
                minZoom={this.getCalculatedMinZoomFromState()}
                maxZoom={2}
                attributionControl={false}
                doubleClickZoom={false}
                zoomControl={false}
                crs={this.mapService.getProjectionType()}
            >



                <ZoomControl position={'topright'} zoomInText={"<img src=" + this.mapService.getPlusIconPath() + " alt='plus' />"} zoomOutText={"<img src=" + this.mapService.getMinusIconPath() + " alt='minus' />"} />
                <CategoryControl />
                <Layers data={this.showPlanService.getJSONResponse()} />

            </Map>
```

And I need to show and hide some components depends on zoom level.

Comment: have you tried `onZoomstart`/`onZoomend` ?

Comment: @megamit Yes bro, This is work. I just make some mistake in handler method (TODO comment without output) But I was sure that there is some alert() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is always trivial :)

On this URL is native leaflet events

http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-event

To use them in React-leaflet you need to add ass attribute event as following ( **`on`** + **event name**) I must add that event caller is not case sensitive

i.e

```
<Map ...  onZoomStart={this.handleZoomStart} onMoveEnd={this.handleMoveEnd} ...> 
</Map
```

Comment: How did you import <Map/>? I imported it as `import { MapContainer as Map } from 'react-leaflet';` but the onLoad, onload, load attributes are not firing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441600/react-leaflet-marker-files-not-found/51222271#51222271

Map Container is not a valid React Leaflet component if I am not wrong.

Comment: Well, it's working for me. If I try to import Map ibstead of MapContainer I get and error. Can you tell me wich library you're using and what version. Seems as if Map has far more options than MapContainer